# XQuery 1.0 - split string after n characters

Tags: xml, xquery

Is it possible, using XQuery 1.0, to split a string, lets say 100 characters long, to a sequence of strings, 10 characters long each?

Another words, I need to split a string after every 10 characters, using XQuery 1.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure; here is one approach:

```
let $width := 10
let $string := '...'
for $i in 0 to string-length($string) idiv $width
let $pos := $i * $width + 1
return substring($string, $pos, $width)
```

Hope this helps,
Christian

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution using a recursive function:

```
declare function local:split($str,$start,$len){
  let $res := substring($str,$start,$len)
  return if ($res) then ($res,local:split($str,$start + $len, $len)) else $res
};

let $x := "sdlfksldfkjsldfkfjsldkjflskfd"
return local:split($x,1,10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way that comes to mind is

```
for $i in 0 to string-length($input)+9 idiv 10
return substring($input, $i*10+1, 10)
```

leaving you to sort out the inevitable off-by-one errors...

Answer (score 1):

With a recursive function, you can do :

```
declare function local:splitString($String as xs:string?, $length as xs:integer) as xs:string* {
  if (exists($String) and string-length($String) > $length) then 
    (substring($String,1,$length), local:splitString(substring($String,$length),$length)) 
  else $String
};
```